# Is c++ STL template parameter precise enough?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stl

For example, c++  std::find_if is implemented like:

```
template <class InputIter, class UnaryPredicate>
InputIter find_if(InputIter begin, InputIter end, UnaryPredicate pred) {
    for (; begin != end; begin++) {
        if (pred(*begin))
            return begin;
    }
    return end;
}
```

- `InputIter` should be `std::input_iterator_tag` type, but in this function, any type which has `operator++` `operator++(int)` can be compiled.
- `UnaryPredicate` should be something like `bool function(const T &value)`, but any function return `int` `double` can be compiled.

Is STL template parameter precise enough ? It seems doesn't check all possible error when compiling.

Can we implement it like:

```
template <T, Iter<? super std::input_iterator<T>>, Pred<? implement bool (const T&)>>
Iter find_if(Iter begin, Iter end, Pred p) {
  for (; begin != end; begin++) {
    if (p(*begin))
      return begin;
  }
  return end;
}
```

In this fake code, I want find_if work for type `T`, it has range in `[begin, end)`, and use `bool (const T &)` to check if it is statisfied ?

Comment: I wouldn't say that these are errors. The fact that `find_if` works not only with iterators, but also pointers is a *feature*, not a bug. Same for the predicate - I can pass a lambda, a functor or a free function and it will still work fine. The point of STL algorithms is to be defined in terms of requirements over the types, not on precise types; if you want, it's a form of compile-time duck typing. If a constraint is not satisfied it simply won't compile.

Comment: Of course there's a flip side of this - namely, the completely unreadable error messages and the fact that obtaining errors depends strictly from the implementation - if some implementation for some reason doesn't use some of the constraints your code compiles, but it's not portable. This will hopefully be fixed by the concepts proposal, upcoming in some next C++ standard.

Comment: By the way, any real implementation would do `++begin`. It is well known that prefix operator can be more efficient because it avoid the temporary copy (to save the old value) and a compiler might not always be able to optimize away the copy (particularily for user type if the definition is not inlined). Any C++ expert know that. And if you are not an expert, then you should have written the code as it.

Comment: yeah, it seems more history and concepts than precise

Comment: I would also think that in simple cases like this one, it might not worth the extra compilation time if the compiler error is already clear enough if the type does not have the appropriate operators.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Pointers *are* random access iterators.

Comment: Maybe `static_assert` can help you restrict the types here so you get a nice error message?

Comment: @Galik, yes, I can write some `static_assert` at the begining in function `find_if`, to check template parameter.  but actually I want real higher-order function, the ability that `API` precisely defines itself.

Comment: For `UnaryPredicate`, the standard specifically doesn't require that it take `T` (the value type of the iterator) and return `bool`. It only requires that the expression `pred(*i) != false` (for iterators `i` in the range) be valid in boolean context.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I think I asked a wrong question, actually I want to discuss the higher-order function in c++, not only STL template parameters.

Comment: Well then, ask the question you actually meant to ask. My [legilimency](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Legilimency) nowadays is not what it used to be.

Comment: You appear to be talking about *concepts* which is a Technical Specification and soon to be added to the language proper (hopefully). As far as I know only `GCC` implements it currently: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different questions hiding here.  I don't know which one you intend to ask.

First one about `find_if`.  The way `find_if` is defined explicitly allows the parameter types you want to reject, and that is usually considered as a feature.  So implementing checks one way or another would not be conformant and would reject valid code.

The second is about the C++ language.  It does not currently offer a way to check or even describe constraints on template parameters more explicitly than by checking usage.  The name used in C++ circles for such a system is *concept*.  There are libraries aiming to help checking them (in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm) for instance), and there is a Technical Specification which has been implemented in GCC describing how the language could be extended to include a language defined notion of concept, but that TS has not yet been incorporated in the standard.